# Phonegap and Twitter Web Intents

Tags: cordova, twitter, webintents

I have a Phonegap 1.3 application. I want to introduce some twitter integration for iOS and Android.

I'd like to use Twitter Web Intents but this gives me white screen with the straightforward set up.

Has anyone successfully integrated Web Intents? Does it require Child Browser functionality and if so, how does that work?

Thanks!

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi Check this may help you [link1](http://a.shinynew.me/post/20369076673/bridging-the-phonegap-twitter-plugin)

or This [link2](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/Twitter)